# Error When Sending String Between Client And Server

Tags: java, network-programming

When I send a String from my client to my server, the server always throws a

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

If I send a Integer or other types other than a String, the exception would not have been thrown and the program runs absolutely fine.

Client Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestingClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9998);

            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("hello");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Server Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class TestingServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9998);
            Socket connectionToClient = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionToClient.getInputStream()));              

            System.out.println(input.readLine());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `"hello"` isn't a `byte[]`. On the client, write the `String` with [`DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) and then `flush()`. Something like

```
outputStream.writeUTF("hello");
outputStream.flush();
```

and on the server, you can't use a `BufferedReader`. You need something like [`DataInputStream.readUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF%28%29)

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
        connectionToClient.getInputStream());
System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
```